# Progressive Enhancement for long-running tasks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, progressive-enhancement

I'm looking for ways to improve a web page that initiates a long-running (>2 minutes) server-side task. The current version of the page just clocks for the full duration of the task, which can be very frustrating to the user.

I already have a few ideas about how I could improve the user's experience, but they all would involve the use of AJAX to some extent. Because of previous experiences that I've had on this project, I know that not all users have JavaScript enabled or available.

Assuming that the server-side process has already been optimized as much as possible, what else could I do to improve the experience of *all* users as much as possible?

Comment: Have you considered adding a service to off-load these long-running tasks to?  Your web pages can then simply start of the process and then (if your end-user's javascript allows it), poll that service to get the progress.  This will enable you to continue to serve pages without interrupting the task and improve your user's experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the long-running server process out-of-band.

When users initiate the task the application can write a message to a queue of some sort; this is typically extremely fast, so users get control back quickly. Once the message is queued, another specialized process (a service, a scheduled task, a cron job, etc.) picks it up and executes the appropriate task at the first opportunity.

For users with javascript enabled, you can set up a timer to check the status of the task via AJAX and alert them when the task is finished.

You can keep your non-javascript users informed by displaying their pending and completed tasks in a common, visible spot on your pages. Of course, they have to keep browsing to benefit from that, so you also need to make it clear that users should occasionally refresh the page if they're waiting for a task to finish.

Comment: I really like the idea of display the tasks completion as they continue browsing. Excellent suggestion, thanks!

Comment: You could also use an <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="15;url=thisPage.html"> tag for non-javascript users.  I personally try to avoid refreshes, but for something like this, in a case where the user doesn't have javascript, I think it's appropriate to refresh the page every 15 seconds or so to update the status.

Answer (score 1):

- create table in database (or in-memory object)
- long-running task will update progress in this table (object)
- web page will display data from this table (or object). how to refresh page - it's your choice.